# How to open an xml file created from a dataset from asp.net 3.5 C# in Ms Office Project 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2008

We have an web application in which we are able to create an xml file from dataset .But when we are trying to open that xml file in MS office Project 2003 it is throwing an error like "File is damaged cannot be open.Use a back up to open this file".
The xml file is created well with all tags .Dont know where it go wrong?
Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution is the a pretty simple on: right click and open with notepad, save and then resave with the xml suffix.

Notepad man. It seems to strip out anything. Except, of course, the text.

Comment: Believe it or not, for XML I actually think that IE is a reasonable tool to check to validity of the file.  @diya should try that.